# Quartz job running forever without waiting

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

I want quartz scheduler to run 50(this number is dynamic) jobs. The Threadpool if of size 3. I don't want any waiting time between any job , basically i want the job to be ready to run again as soon as it finishes. I know this can be done using Java in built schedulers.
I could find any trigger which takes 0 as the argument. Can this be achieved in Quartz ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use a simple trigger that allows you to specify a very short period length (the minimum is 1ms). I think you could also implement a JobListener that gets notified whenever a job finishes executing and you can use this listener to dynamically reschedule the executed job to "execute now".

BTW: using a thread pool of size 3 and 50+ **continuously** running jobs will result in lots of misfires. In order to be able to run 50+ jobs **continuously**, you will need a thread pool with 50+ threads.

Comment: I want my job not to schedule until it is executed once , similar to java's schedule at fixed rate. Can this be done ? I guess this will prevent misfires